# How to rename docker image name?

Tags: docker

I saved a file whose format is `.tar` by `docker save` ,and then I load it into another server by `docker load`. When it succeeded, the docker give me a tip which is showed in following word.

```
The image file:V2.0.0Beta1-test already exists, renaming the old one with ID sha256:46952aea8dd30da5a2645d28930381c0ed5f72acd4fac43ea8556cc360d22cf7 to empty string
Loaded image: file:V2.0.0Beta1-test
```

And the old image should be saved,the new one need to save.What should I do now?

Comment: You are probably looking for the `docker tag` command.

Comment: Your adivice is that I change the old one's tag?But now  I can't find the old image.How can I find it?Or when I docker load the image,the operation failed?@Henry

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can tag a docker image using `docker tag`, actually, it creates an image with a name that you specify in docker tag command.

> Create a tag TARGET_IMAGE that refers to SOURCE_IMAGE

**Tag an image referenced by ID**

> To tag a local image with ID “0e5574283393” into the “fedora”
>   repository with “version1.0”:
>
> $ docker tag 0e5574283393 fedora/httpd:version1.0

Suppose you have an image named **Beta1-test**, you can tag like

`docker tag Beta1-test Beta1-test_old`

This will tag the Beta1-test image with new Beta1-test to Beta1-test_old.

Docker tag is just a way of referring to your image.
So you can remove the **Beta1-test** using

`docker rmi -f Beta1-test`

now, as you have that image with new tag **Beta1-test_old**

Now you are able to build image like
docker build -t Beta1-test

**Beta1-test** this is your new image after the build, and we tag the previous one with Beta1-test_old.

You have both new having name **Beta1-test** and old having name **Beta1-test_old**

You can view you docker images using this command.

```
docker images
```

or

```
docker images Beta1-test
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful. I do some tries and it worked.I changed the old one's tag but when I listed the images ,I found that there is two records about the old one, the different point is different tag.So I deleted one record.Then I load the new file,it worked. The new one and old one are saved ,we can distinct them by tag.Thanks a lot! @Adiii